# Question on URLFOR SPACE

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-experience, salesforce1-app

I am using a URLFOR function in the URL field. When i am entering 'X Y' for the query string parameter, the output of the URL is https://www.google.com?X+Y=777 instead of https://www.google.com?X%20Y=777.

As per the HTML encoding, Space should be encoded to %20 but why SFDC is converting to + ?

URLFOR("https://www.google.com",null,['X Y'=Opportunity.StageName])

Comment: Use of plus is a far older convention than % encoding. I guess they simply have not changed this since implementing this function, perhaps for backwards compatibility?